# locking a resource from a pool while allowing others to order other resources from the pool of resource

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

I'm building a website for ordering resources. I have a pool of resources (say 10 resources) and when a user wants to order a resource, I check which is free and assigning it to the user.
I'm using MYSQL innoDB table and locking the row using

```
update ResourceTable SET SOMEFIELD='1'
```

but if the first transaction didn't finish yet and now another user is searching (using

```
select * FROM ResourceTable WHERE SOMEFIELD!='1' LOCK IN SHARE MODE
```

, the user is waiting for the 1st transaction to finish (although there are other free resources).
If I remove the `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`, I will get a resource that is supposed to be locked.

How can I allow multiple users to order resources without waits?

(I though of somehow selecting rows that are not locked -> not exist in MYSQL)

Answer (score 0):

The solution may be to lock the *entire table* before changing the value of SOMEFIELD.  Updating this value is a very quick operation, so even if a few incoming requests to your site need to access the resource pool near-simultaneously, and one request is in the process of changing SOMEFIELD, the others have to wait only a fraction of a second for it to release the lock on the table.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is that I was looking for a solution without lock wait (since there are other free resources)